# AMP and too-wide tables

Tags: css, html-table, amp-html

My blog posts use the `<table>` tag quite heavily (for tabulated data, not a format hack) but when using AMP on mobile things spill off the edge of the screen relatively frequently, or else things get
over-
word-
wrapped.
 Looking around the web, I found [this ingenious/ugly hack](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/) but I am looking for a better solution; some sort of [Bootstrap Carousel](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-moving-box-carousel) might be a possible solution, ***if*** it could be done in pure CSS.

Here's a [typical screen](https://whatjapanthinks.com/2017/07/20/japans-summer-not-liked-by-almost-two-thirds/amp/) with the last column chopped off when you narrow the browser window. Note that using a desktop browser the only way to scroll I can see is to select text and drag to the right. On mobile, one can use touch, but there is no UI hint that there is chopped-off data:

[image]

Note that I generate the table from raw data in a plugin, so I could re-author the data in some other form if there were a `<div>`-based solution, for instance.

Comment: Unless there's something special about AMP... you can wrap the table in a div and on that div you can set `overflow-x: auto` for a scroll-able table

Comment: @Ihazkode unfortunately, [`overflow: auto` is banned](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#properties).

Comment: I see, yeah I figured there might be something different about AMP but I have no experience in that area.

Comment: This should be helpful for to use tables in mobile devices. Better ux. https://codepen.io/dbushell/pen/wGaamR

Comment: @hunzaboy nice! But it also has the `overflow: auto` tag. Scroll bars on AMP are a big no-no, so that's why I was asking about a carousel-style solution.

Comment: @KenY-N , i won't do carousel style as it will again create more issues on mobile. You can add a tooltip on mobile screen saying "Scroll Right/Left for more" this way your users will understand that there is more content. OR you can get rid of tables on mobile and make something vertical. I am sure a good media query will do that. :)

Comment: Hmm, I found [this page](https://hashnode.com/post/really-responsive-tables-using-css3-flexbox-cijzbxd8n00pwvm53sl4l42cx), and [this solution](https://codepen.io/vasansr/full/jWazPM) looks better than a floating arrow. In my sample table above I could squeeze the "Male/Percentage" and "Female/Percentage" cells into a single column, although having to hardcode minimum widths is a bit hacky IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your tables scrollable horizontally by embedding them into an amp-carousel:

```
 <amp-carousel height="300" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel">
   <table class="result">...</table>
  </amp-carousel>
```

The key is to use the carousel type `carousel` (it's the default) and to combine it with a `fixed-height` layout that matches your table's height.

[Here](http://output.jsbin.com/sawexinuzo) is a working sample on JSBIN.

Comment: Interesting! The only problem I see is trying to find a suitable height, but I could estimate that from the number of rows in the table, but that's a low-pain change so I'll give it a go and see how it looks on mobile. Oh, and I found this [`<amp-table>` feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2745).